# How can I effect to another thread? (for example: to setSelect the checkbox)

Tags: java, netbeans

I created two "jFrame form" with netbeans. I can open the both same time. This codes run but no effect. I try to setSelect a checkbox in form2 with a button in form1. Somehow, I can't effect another thread. Could you please fix it for me. Thanks. (sorry my bad English, I am learning English, too)

This is form1.java (I removed some automatic codes)

```
package test;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class form1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public form1() {
    initComponents();
}                                      
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  new form2().setVisible(true);
}                                        
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            final form2 click = new form2();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            click.jCheckBox1.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
    );
}                                        
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    new form1().setVisible(true);
    }
    });
}  
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
// End of variables declaration                  
}
```

This is form2.java (I removed some automatic codes)

```
package test;
public class form2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public form2() {
    initComponents();
}                 
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new form2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}  
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;
// End of variables declaration                
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `jButton2ActionPerformed` method, you're creating a new JFrame which is never shown. You're **not** manipulating the JFrame you displayed in `jButton1ActionPerformed`.

Try this:

```
package test;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
public class form1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private form2 click = null; // this will hold the second JFrame (the one with the checkbox)
public form1() {
    initComponents();
}                                      
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  if (click == null) { // only create the second JFrame once
      click = new form2(); // this stores the second JFrame with the name "click"
      click.setVisible(true);
  }
}
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (click != null) { // don't do anything if the second JFrame isn't displayed yet
                    click.jCheckBox1.setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        }
    );
}                                        
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    new form1().setVisible(true);
    }
    });
}  
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
// End of variables declaration                  
}
```

BTW, it is bad form and very confusing for class names to start with a lower case letter. Rename `form1` to `Form1` and `form2` to `Form2`.

Comment: Thanks Alvin. But please explain more. How can do this or Can't I do this.

Comment: Last question, at this stage; Can I opposite;

I mean, just like bridge. I will put checkbox in form1 and setselect this checkbox with a button in form2. Thus, I can effect each other.

Comment: @Sertaç: you could add a static field to the `form1` class which contains the instance, such as `public static form1 myForm1;` and in the "main" method use something similar to what you used in "jButton1ActionPerformed": `myForm1 = new form1(); myForm1.setVisible(true);`. Then in `form2` you can refer to `form1` with `form1.myForm1`. For example, `form1.myForm1.jCheckBox1.setSelected(true);`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much Alvin.